# FIRST_VALUE not working as I'd expect with PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Here is my test set:

```
master_ref  ref          value
56279276    56279325    FRAME ASSEMBLY1
56279276    384062724   FRAME ASSEMBLY2
56279276    443450775   FRAME ASSEMBLY3
```

I want to retrieve the value field based on the highest ref given a master_ref.

Here is what I tried that just return everything:

```
select first_value(value) over (partition by ida3masterreference order by ida3a4 desc) value, ida3masterreference, ida3a4 from sts_epm_title1;
```

I expected to only get one result:

```
master_ref    ref         value
56279276    443450775   FRAME ASSEMBLY3
```

But it still returns all 3 results.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: If you still want to use the `first_value()` then use a where statement to decrease the rows. `select * from (select first_value(value) over (partition by ida3masterreference order by ida3a4 desc) fvalue, value, ida3masterreference, ida3a4 from sts_epm_title1)a where fvalue=value;` That should give you only the first value rows.

Answer (score 3):

`first_value()` is an analytic function, so it does not reduce the number of rows.  You apparently want an aggregation function so use the `keep` syntax:

```
select max(value) keep (dense_rank first order by ida3a4 desc) as value, 
       ida3masterreference, max(ida3a4) as ida3a4
from sts_epm_title1
group by ida3masterreference
```

Comment: Perfect!  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER/RANK`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   select row_number() over (partition by ida3masterreference 
                             order by ida3a4 desc) AS rn, t.*
   from sts_epm_title1 t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```